# php Mongo driver cursor traveling take long so much

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a query like this

```
$results = $collection->find([
        'status'      => "pending",
        'short_code'  => intval($shortCode),
        'create_time' => ['$lte' => time()],
    ])
    ->limit(self::BATCH_NUMBER)
    ->sort(["priority" => -1, "create_time" => 1]);
```

Where BATCH_SIZE is 70.

and i use the result of query like below :

```
foreach ($results as $mongoId => $result) {
}
```

or trying to convert in to array like :

```
iterator_to_array($results);
```

mongo fetch data and traveling on iterate timing is :

```
FetchTime: 0.003173828125 ms
IteratorTime: 4065.1459960938 ms
```

As you can see, fetching data by mongo is too fast, but iterating (in both case of using iterator_to_array or using foreach) is slow.

It is a queue for sending messages to another server. Destination server accept less than 70 documents per each request. So i forced to fetch 70 document. anyway. I want to fetch 70 documents from 1,300,000 documents and we have problem here.
query try to fetch first 70 documents which have query conditions, send them and finally delete them from collection.

can anybody help? why it takes long? or is there any config for accelerating for php or mongo?

Another thing, when total number of data is like 100,000 (isntead of 1,300,000) the traveling is fast. traveling time will increase by increasing number of total documents.

Comment: How many results are actually being returned? At 4 seconds I would presume it's not actually a small amount. Perhaps you should consider that instead of returning such a large amount of results, you might actually need something to "reduce" the resultset on the server itself. So you need to give some context. Being the number of results actually being returned, and where that is a large number ( as in 1000's ) then you should explain why exactly you need to return 1000's of results and what you intend to do with them as a result.

Comment: I need 70 document from 1,300,000 document. Actually my BATCH_NUMBER is 70. As you can see, fetching from mongo is fast. traveling between results is the problem.

Comment: Well there's your problem. Why on earth would you possibly need to cycle through 1.3 million documents just to take out 70? That's what "query" conditions are for. So if there is some other logic that determines the `70` then that needs to happen on the server. How are you determining the `70` you actually need? Include the details **in your question by editing it and explaining** what the code processing the cursor is actually doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was because of sorting.

The problem :
Fetching data from mongo was fast, but traveling in iterator was slow using foreach.

solution :
there was a sort which we used. sorting by priority DESC and create_time ASC. These fileds was index ASC seperatly. Indexing priority DESC and create_time ASC together fixed problem.

```
db.queue_1.createIndex( { "priority" : -1, "create_time" : 1 } )
```

order of fileds on indexing is important. means you should use priority at first. then use create_time.
because when you try to sort your query, you sort them like below :

```
.sort({priority : -1, create_time : 1});
```